# How to convert datetime.time columns in dataframe to string

Tags: datetime, pandas, dataframe

I've been struggling to convert two columns in a pandas.
The frame contains many columns, and 2 columns with dates: 'datelog'(is a date) and 'Timeofday' (is a time).
The column datelog is a string.
The column  Timeofday is  a datetime.time() format.
The dateframe display is as folows:

```
     datelog Timeofday
0  30-APR-15  14:15:43
1  30-APR-15  14:16:13
2  30-APR-15  14:16:43
3  30-APR-15  14:17:13
4  30-APR-15  14:17:43
5  30-APR-15  14:18:13
6  30-APR-15  14:18:43
7  30-APR-15  14:19:13
8  30-APR-15  14:19:43
9  30-APR-15  14:20:13
```

My goal is to concatenate these two column to use them as a index for a timeseries. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use something like this to create your index:

```
df.index = df['datelog'] + ' ' + df['Timeofday'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) if want `DatetimeIndex`. If not, use [`ysearka`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38098460/2901002) solution:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.datelog) + pd.to_timedelta(df.Timeofday)

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-04-30 14:15:43', '2015-04-30 14:16:13',
               '2015-04-30 14:16:43', '2015-04-30 14:17:13',
               '2015-04-30 14:17:43', '2015-04-30 14:18:13',
               '2015-04-30 14:18:43', '2015-04-30 14:19:13',
               '2015-04-30 14:19:43', '2015-04-30 14:20:13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```